# Dispatch window load event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to dispatch the window's `load` event in Javascript.  There is plenty of documentation on how to dispatch mouse events, But I can't find any on load events.  It only needs to work in Firefox.  It would be equally helpful if I could "spy" on the window's load event, because then I could just call the function.  Using the "Event spy" addon isn't working because it requires me to open the dom inspector, which i can't do until after the page is finished loading.

I'm making a grease monkey script.  So I don't know which function it is that I'm trying to invoke.

Comment: Why don't you just handle the onload event and call that handler explicitly instead of firing the onload event?

Answer (score 4):

```
var load_event = document.createEvent('Event');  
load_event.initEvent('load', false, false);  
window.dispatchEvent(load_event);
```

works fine in my environment.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) are fired differently than mouse events. Here is how to fire a load event:

```
var load_event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
load_event.initEvent("load", true, true);
window.dispatchEvent(load_event);
```

**References**

- [UIEvents: initEvent](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#widl-Event-initEvent)
- [DOM Features](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/DOM_features)

Comment: Thanks for the script. The load event must be fired at the Window object, not Document

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2021 year**

```
var load_event = new Event("load"); 
window.dispatchEvent(load_event);
```

[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)